# Unfamiliar C++ code with strange return types

Tags: c++, function, return-type

I encountered some really strange c++ code that I have never seen before, even though I have a little bit of experience. I tryed searching for it but I had no luck. This is super strange and either im really stupid or this is some wizard magic code. My question is how can the GetHelixCenter have a bool return type but still fill the helixcenterpos[] array? The GetHelixCenter function is called from another function like:

```
Double_t helixcenterpos[2];
GetHelixCenter(pparam,helixcenterpos);
```

and later on helixcenterpos is accessed:

```
Double_t xpos = helixcenterpos[0];
```

but it is untouched in between. The GetHelixCenter function looks like:

```
Bool_t AliV0ReaderV1::GetHelixCenter(const AliExternalTrackParam *track,Double_t center[2]){

  // Get Center of the helix track parametrization

  Int_t charge=track->Charge();
  Double_t b=fInputEvent->GetMagneticField();

  Double_t  helix[6];
  track->GetHelixParameters(helix,b);

  Double_t xpos =  helix[5];
  Double_t ypos =  helix[0];
  Double_t radius = TMath::Abs(1./helix[4]);
  Double_t phi = helix[2];

  if(phi < 0){
    phi = phi + 2*TMath::Pi();
  }

  phi -= TMath::Pi()/2.;
  Double_t xpoint =  radius * TMath::Cos(phi);
  Double_t ypoint =  radius * TMath::Sin(phi);

  if(b<0){
    if(charge > 0){
      xpoint = - xpoint;
      ypoint = - ypoint;
    }
  }
  if(b>0){
    if(charge < 0){
      xpoint = - xpoint;
      ypoint = - ypoint;
    }
  }
  center[0] =  xpos + xpoint;
  center[1] =  ypos + ypoint;

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: This function always returns 1, which is a double. Though we seem to have Double_t and Bool_t going on. However, the return is ignored, and the centrepos (two things in an array) is changed in the code and therefore helixcenterpos[0] isthe first thing in the array not the return value.

Comment: The really strange thing about this code is `typedef`-ing all those standard types – and don't have any meaningful explanation for...

Comment: @doctorlove `1` is not a double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `helixcenterpos` array is passed as the second argument:

```
Bool_t AliV0ReaderV1::GetHelixCenter(const AliExternalTrackParam *track,Double_t center[2]){
```

Here, `center` decays to a pointer to the first value of your original array. Hence

```
center[0] =  xpos + xpoint;
center[1] =  ypos + ypoint;
```

write to that array.

---

It should be pointed out, that the parameter would be better chosen as

```
Bool_t AliV0ReaderV1::GetHelixCenter(const AliExternalTrackParam *track,Double_t (&center)[2]){
```

so that you are sure that `GetHelixCenter` always receives the correct array.

Comment: Yes. You are right. The code is just a little sketchy and I didn't see it. Thanks :)

Comment: Btw. the decay-to-pointer thing was inherited from C and C++'s original intention to be compatible with C. But since C doesn't have references, passing a reference to an array can be defined more sensibly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. Are you unsure why your function is capable of modifying the external array?

That's because in C++ when passing arrays, you're actually passing a pointer to the start of the array, instead of passing a copy of the array, as is the case with non-array types.

So, for example:

```cpp
void myFunction(int a) {
    a = 3;
}

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    myFunction(a);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

would still print `0`. Because the integer is copied when calling `myFunction` and that copy is modified.

But when doing:

```cpp
void myFunction(int a[1]) {
    a[0] = 3;
}

int main() {
    int a[1];
    myFunction(a);
    std::cout << a[0] << std::endl;
}
```

would print `3`, as you're actually modifying the first element of the array pointed to by a.

Comment: Yes this is exaclty what I meant. It was unclear to me because I wans't aware of the syntax. I thought you had to do * or & or soemthing. Thanks :)

Comment: Passing an array and passing a pointer is basically the same. E.g. you could change the signature of your function to

Bool_t AliV0ReaderV1::GetHelixCenter(const AliExternalTrackParam *track,Double_t *center)

and it would still compile and have exactly the same behavior.